# where i miss the semicolon?

Tags: java, android, android-webview

I have this code:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        WebView webview=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/1.html");
        @JavascriptInterface
                public void showToast(String areaName){
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "You clicked on "+areaName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

and when I run my code, i get 2 error:

> Error:(25, 38) java: ';' expected
>
> Error:(25, 54) java: ';' expected

and when i click on the errors, courser goes on this parts:

```
        public void showToast(String areaName){
```

but i cant find out where i miss semicolon.
can some one give me a light?:)

Comment: Can you check your curly brackets ?

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    WebView webview=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/1.html");

}


@JavascriptInterface
            public void showToast(String areaName){
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "You clicked on "+areaName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

You can't create method within another method

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring a method inside of another one.  Separate the two like so:

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        WebView webview=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/1.html");
    }

  @JavascriptInterface
                public void showToast(String areaName){
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "You clicked on "+areaName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to define method within a method which is not allowed.

So if you close `onCreate` method just before your annotation `@JavascriptInterface` and remove ending brace bracket it would work.